# How do you find certain parameters?

Tags: java, arraylist

For example I have:

```
ArrayList<Student> stu = new ArrayList<Student>();
stu.add(new HighSchoolStudent("Jem", "Finch", 11, 3.4));
stu.add(new Student("Scout", "Finch", 4));
stu.add(new HighSchoolStudent("Boo", "Radley", 12, 1.7));
stu.add(new HighSchoolStudent("Atticus", "Finch", 12, 4.8));
stu.add(new Student("Patrick", "Henry", 9));
stu.add(new Student("Patrick", "Henry", 11));

ArrayList<Teacher> tea = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
tea.add(new Teacher("Betsy", "Ross", "Home Ec"));
tea.add(new Teacher("Ada", "Lovelace", "Mathematics"));
tea.add(new Teacher("Grace", "Hopper", "Computer Science"));
tea.add(new Teacher("Marie", "Curie", "Chemistry"));
tea.add(new Teacher("Dolly", "Madison", "Government"));
tea.add(new Teacher("Maya", "Angelou", "English Composition"));

School sch = new School(stu, tea);
System.out.println("\n\njust seniors: \n" + sch.getGradeLevel(12));
```

and both HighSchoolStudent and Student has the parameter (LastName,FirstName,GradeLevel,gpa). How would I create a method (getGradeLevel) in another class that finds when GradeLevel is 12, it prints only that part of the arrayList? So I want the output to be:

```
Radley, Boo
   Grade Level: 12
   ID #: 5
   GPA: 1.7
Finch, Atticus
   Grade Level: 12
   ID #: 6
   GPA: 4.8
```

My code of the school class is

```
class School
{
 public ArrayList <Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
 public ArrayList <Teacher> teacher = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
 public String listOfNames;
 private String gradeList;
public School()
{
}
public School(ArrayList <Student> stu, ArrayList <Teacher> tec)
{
student = stu;
teacher = tec;
}

public String getGradeLevel(int grade)
{
//Need help with this part
}




public String toString()
{//Makes a string with last, first name and subject
 listOfNames+=("\nFaculty:\n");
for (int i=0;i<teacher.size();i++)
 {
  listOfNames +=" "+teacher.get(i);
}

listOfNames+="\nStudents:\n";
for (int i=0;i<student.size();i++)
{
  listOfNames +=student.get(i)+" ";
}
return listOfNames;
}//End toString
}
```

Comment: Look into how you iterate over elements in a `List`.

Comment: why do you think the content of "school" matters?  What have you tried in fact?

Comment: School matters because in the void main is                     School sch = new School(stu, tea);
  System.out.println(sch);

  System.out.println("\n\njust seniors: \n" + sch.getGradeLevel(12));                                              School is called

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Student s:stu){
  if(s.getGradeLevel()==12){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

This answer assumes that you have declared a method `getGradeLevel()` in the `Student` class that returns the student's grade level, and that you have properly overridden `Student.toString()`.

Comment: I need to create a method getGradeLevel which finds whenever gradeLevel is 12.  I made the method                          `public String getGradeLevel(int grade)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<student.size();i++)
    {
       gradeList+= student.get(i).toString();
    }
    return gradeList;
}`                                                                     But this prints all of the stu.  I only want to have it return the arraylist position where gradeLevel is 12.

Comment: @Hulu You have a parameter passed in (grade) but you haven't used in your code.  That's really an obvious problem isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter method...

When you assign values to your objects through the constructor you can simply set the value of instance fields with these values. Then the getter method finds the value of these fields when using the getSomeValue() method as you mention in your post; which is excellent encapsulation. Encapsulation is a good coding practice. You can access specific fields of an object by calling methods on an object reference that points to said object.

Some sample code is below to illustrate this.  You can easily modify it for your specific purposes.

Sample code:

```
package SchoolRulez;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student { 

  private String school;
  private String name;
  private double GPA;
  private int grade;

  ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

 Student(String school, String name, double GPA, int grade) { 
     this.school = school;
     this.name = name;
     this.GPA = GPA;
     this.grade = grade;

 }

 public void addStudent(Student s) { 

         students.add(s); 
         return;
 }

 public double getGPA() { 

    return this.GPA;
 }

 public int getGrade() { 
   return this.grade;

 }

 public String getName(){ 
  return this.name;

 }


 // the rest of the 'getter' methods can follow the pattern of getGPA()  and getGrade() above :D

//find a specific grade level
 public void getGradeLevel(int grade) { 

     for(Student s: students) { 

        if(s.getGrade() == grade) { 
              System.out.println("this student " + s.getName() + " is in " + s.getGrade() + " grade");

        } // end if
      }// end enhanced for loop


 }// end getGradeLevel() method




}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a HashMap

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Student>> = stu  new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Student>>();

ArrayList<Student> studentsGrade4 = new ArrayList<Student>();
studentsGrade4.add(new Student("Scout", "Finch", 4));
stu.put(new Integer(4), studentsGrade4);
ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent> studentsGrade11 = new ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent>();
studentsGrade12.add(new Student("Tom", "Skreech", 12));
studentsGrade12.add(new Student("Patrick", "Henry", 12))
stu.put(new Integer(12), studentsGrade11);

ArrayList<Student> highschoolSeniors = stu.get(12);
for (Student s : highSchoolSeniors) {
  System.out.println(s.toString());
}
```

This is useful because it will separate your students by each grade. It is even easier when you populate the HashMap by iterating through a list of students. This is great when you have a large list of students and need to retrieve a grade level very quickly.